# Clock.fixed what is the role of zone

Tags: java

According to the javadoc for [`Clock.fixed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#fixed), zone is:

> zone - the time-zone to use to convert the instant to date-time, not null

But my code doesn't seem to be affected by using a different zone.

```
Clock mockClock = Clock.fixed(Instant.parse("2017-04-10T17:59:00Z"), 
                ZoneId.of("UTC"));      
System.out.println("ZonedDateTime using clock "+ZonedDateTime.now(mockClock));
```

In the above code, whether I set the timezone as UTC or America/Chicago, the output is the same:

```
ZonedDateTime using clock 2017-04-10T17:59Z[UTC]
```

If it doesn't change the timezone, what is the role of `zone`?

Comment: I suppose you try with Joda-Time [link](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html#TimeZones)

Comment: I tested with `Clock.fixed(Instant.parse("2017-04-10T17:59:00Z"), ZoneId.of("America/Chicago"))` and the output is `2017-04-10T12:59-05:00[America/Chicago]`. Where and how are you setting the "America/Chicago" timezone?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, a `Clock` instance retrieved using one of the static methods

```
Clock.system(ZoneId z)
Clock.systemDefaultZone()
Clock.systemUTC()
```

is a "running" clock that returns the current time. A `Clock` always tracks UTC, but also knows its timezone, which it uses when returning date/time values.

If you read the Javadoc carefully you'll see that `Clock.fixed()` returns a special type of clock that is not running, that is, it is always set to a specific instant and does not change with time.

`ZonedDateTime.now(Clock clock)` queries the given clock and returns the current time adjusted for the `Clock`'s timezone.

So when you do

```
Clock mockClock = Clock.fixed(Instant.parse("2017-04-10T17:59:00Z"), ZoneId.of("UTC"));
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(mockClock);
```

the following happens:

1. A special "not running" clock is created that is set to the date/time you gave, with a timezone specification of UTC.
2. The `ZonedDateTime.now(mockClock)` call reads the current value of the clock, which in your case is fixed, and creates a `ZonedDateTime` with the clock value and a timezone of UTC.